# Last value based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following query to extract data from SQL Server.

```
SELECT  
"vendor"."vendornum" AS Number, 
"vendor"."vendornam" AS Name,
"product"."prductnum" AS ProductNumber 
"product"."prductdsc" AS Description 
"po_lnrcpt"."um_code",
"porcpt"."received_date" AS DateReceived,
"po_lnrcpt"."ovruntcst" AS Price, 

FROM   
(((("Test"."dbo"."company" "company" INNER JOIN 
"Test"."dbo"."porcpt" 
"porcpt" ON "company"."co_num"="porcpt"."co_num")
INNER JOIN 
"Test"."dbo"."po" "po" ON "porcpt"."po_tky"="po"."po_tky") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"Test"."dbo"."po_lnrcpt" "po_lnrcpt" ON 
"porcpt"."po_rcvtky"="po_lnrcpt"."po_rcvtky") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"Test"."dbo"."product" "product" ON 
"po_lnrcpt"."prdtky"="product"."prdtky") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
"Test"."dbo"."vendor" "vendor" ON 
"po"."ventky"="vendor"."ventky"

 WHERE  
 "po_lnrcpt"."rcvqty"<>0 AND 
 "porcpt"."rcvstsflg"='C'
```

Is there anyway I can use the MAX or some other function to show the last price of a product from specific vendor.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "last"? Most recent? Highest price? Last one found by a general query? You ask if you should use `MAX`.... well, yes, if you want the maximum price, but you didn't say specifically.

Comment: Sorry to mention, yes the most recent price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way with a CTE. This can be dine with another inner join in the original query too. Also, you could use ROW_NUMBER(). This is off the assumption that the DateReceived column is the date column which determines the "most recent"

```
with cte as(
SELECT  
    vendor.vendornum AS Number, 
    vendor.vendornam AS Name,
    product.prductnum AS ProductNumber 
    product.prductdsc AS Description 
    po_lnrcpt.um_code,
    porcpt.received_date AS DateReceived,
    po_lnrcpt.ovruntcst AS Price, 

FROM   
Test.dbo.company company INNER JOIN 
Test.dbo.porcpt 
porcpt ON company.co_num=porcpt.co_num
INNER JOIN 
Test.dbo.po po ON porcpt.po_tky=po.po_tky
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Test.dbo.po_lnrcpt po_lnrcpt ON 
porcpt.po_rcvtky=po_lnrcpt.po_rcvtky
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Test.dbo.product product ON 
po_lnrcpt.prdtky=product.prdtky
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Test.dbo.vendor vendor ON 
po.ventky=vendor.ventky

WHERE  
 po_lnrcpt.rcvqty<>0 AND 
 porcpt.rcvstsflg='C')



select
    c.Number
    ,c.Name
    ,c.ProductNumber
    ,c.Description
    ,c.um_code
    ,c.DateReceived
    ,c.Price
from cte c
inner join
    (select Number, max(DateReceived) dt
     from cte
     group by Number) c2 on c2.dt = c.DateReceived and c2.Number = c.Number
```

**ROW_NUMBER() VERSION**

```
with cte as(
SELECT  
    vendor.vendornum AS Number, 
    vendor.vendornam AS Name,
    product.prductnum AS ProductNumber 
    product.prductdsc AS Description 
    po_lnrcpt.um_code,
    porcpt.received_date AS DateReceived,
    po_lnrcpt.ovruntcst AS Price, 
    RN = row_number() over (partition by vendor.vendornum order by porcpt.received_date desc)
FROM   
Test.dbo.company company INNER JOIN 
Test.dbo.porcpt 
porcpt ON company.co_num=porcpt.co_num
INNER JOIN 
Test.dbo.po po ON porcpt.po_tky=po.po_tky
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Test.dbo.po_lnrcpt po_lnrcpt ON 
porcpt.po_rcvtky=po_lnrcpt.po_rcvtky
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Test.dbo.product product ON 
po_lnrcpt.prdtky=product.prdtky
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
Test.dbo.vendor vendor ON 
po.ventky=vendor.ventky

WHERE  
 po_lnrcpt.rcvqty<>0 AND 
 porcpt.rcvstsflg='C')



select
    c.Number
    ,c.Name
    ,c.ProductNumber
    ,c.Description
    ,c.um_code
    ,c.DateReceived
    ,c.Price
from cte c
where RN = 1
```

Comment: getting error on next Select statement."Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'."

Comment: Sorry again forget the end parenthesis, getting Old.

Comment: No worries @Abbas